# What does this function do, and how can I know what it does?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, tree, binary-tree

How to know what the code below does?
How can I approach this kind of question?

Can you explain the code? I'm finding it really hard to understand this function.

The input is:

```
arr[] = {-1, 17, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 55, -1,4, -1, 15, 11, 2, 3};
Tree *p = BuildTreeFromArray(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));
```

My question: what does the function do, and if I want to draw the tree, what should it look like?

The `Tree struct` is :

```
typedef struct tree {  
    int data;    
    struct tree *right;    
    struct tree *left;
} Tree;
```

The function is:

```
Tree *BuildTreeFromArray(int* arr, int size) {   
    Tree *resTree, *right, *left;    
    int halfSize= size/2;    

    resTree = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));    
    if (size <= 0 || resTree == NULL)    
       return NULL;    
    if (size == 1) {
        if (arr[0] == -1)    
            resTree = NULL;    
        else {    
            resTree->data = arr[0];    
            resTree->left = NULL;    
            resTree->right = NULL;
        }    
    } else if (arr[halfSize] == -1)    
        return NULL;
    else {    
        resTree->data = arr[halfSize];    
        if (arr[halfSize/2] != -1) {    
            left = BuildTreeFromArray(arr, halfSize);    
            resTree->left = left;
        }  
        else
            resTree->left = NULL;
        if (arr[halfSize + (halfSize / 2) + 1] != -1) {    
            right = BuildTreeFromArray(arr+halfSize+1, halfSize);    
            resTree->right = right;
        }
        else 
            resTree->right = NULL;
    }
    return resTree;
}
```

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: until the first else (that is ok) , I don't really get  the recursive calls. @ScottHunter

Comment: It might help to properly indent the code.

Comment: Read about how and why correct indent of code is important. The posted code is unreadable...

Comment: You won't be able to understand the code if you can't read it. Don't mix clauses with braces and clauses without braces on the same structure. And fix your indenting. /// Then. get a pencil and paper, and work through the program, writing down the various variables and their current value. (Keep in mind that a recursive call create a net set of variables.)

Comment: l already did that and I got very confused at the end ....  it would help if u give me an advice of how to really understand if the code and what is the main part ....something like that  @ikegami

Comment: Re "*l already did that*", What did you end up with?

Comment: `if (size <= 0 || resTree == NULL) return NULL; ` Memory leak when `size <= 0`

Comment: `resTree = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));` Don't cast `malloc`

Comment: @ikegami ,I checked it once more , it's 15 (not 16)

Comment: You could try running it using a debugger and actually *see* what it does.

Comment: u can add a number in the array and assume its 16 , maybe that can help u understand it better? @ikegami

Comment: @ScottHunter ,I'm sorry I didn't learn how to do that

Comment: Translating the code to a human language, we may get something like this (glancing over some less important details): "To build a tree from an array: If the size of the array is 0, then it is an empty tree. Otherwise, if the size is 1, it is a one-element tree. Otherwise, pick the middle element, build a tree from the portion of the array to the left of it, then build a tree from the portion of the array to the right of it, then combine these two trees into a bigger tree with the middle as the root". If you understand how it works, grokking the code is a purely technical issue.

Comment: thank u ! @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: The less-important details are that we can also create an empty tree when its root would be equal to -1. This part of the code is rather poorly written, there are checks for -1 in 3 different places, these should have been consolidated to a single place.

Comment: (Ignore my now-deleted comments by 16. They were wrong)

Answer (score 3):

It builds a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) by dividing the array in two halves plus a midpoint (`[...left...][data][...right...]`), and building a tree from those halves.

A midpoint value of `-1` indicates a leaf, and so does a size of 1.

```
[-1  17  -1  03  -1  -1  -1][55][-1  04  -1  15  11  02  03] 
               ______________/\______________
              /                              \
[-1  17  -1][03][-1  -1  -1]    [-1  04  -1][15][11  02  03]
       ______/                         ______/\______
      /                               /              \
[-1][17][-1]                    [-1][04][-1]    [11][02][03]
                                                   __/\__
                                                  /      \
                                              [][11][][][03][]
```

---

The function can be written much more clearly.

```
Tree *BuildTreeFromArray(int* arr, size_t size) {   
    if ( size == 0 )
        return NULL;

    size_t halfSize = size / 2;
    int data = arr[halfSize];
    if ( data == -1 )
        return NULL;

    Tree *node = malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    if ( !resTree )
       return NULL;

    node->data  = data;
    node->left  = BuildTreeFromArray( arr,            halfSize );
    node->right = BuildTreeFromArray( arr+halfSize+1, halfSize );

    return node;
}
```

---

As an aside, the minimum size of the array required for a tree of depth N is

min_array_size(0) = 0
min_array_size(n) = 1 + 2 * min_array_size(n-1)

or

min_array_size(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1

Answer (score 0):

The code is just horrible and not worth explaining in details. It needs a complete rewrite.

But here is a tip...

Try to look at this array

```
-1, 17, -1, 3, -1, -1, -1, 55, -1, 4, -1, 15, 11, 2, 3
```

as

```
                           55

            3                             15

    17             -1              4              2

-1      -1     -1      -1      -1     -1      11     3
```

or after removing all -1 elements simply

```
                           55

            3                             15

    17                             4              2

                                              11     3
```

or

```
                           55
                          /  \
                         3   15
                        /   /  \ 
                       17  4    2
                               / \
                              11  3
```

So that's what the code do. It builds a tree from an array. Array elements with value -1 means "no further data in this part of the tree"

Comment: thanks for your precious time !, but as u know ,the university posts the solutions of the exams but they don't explain how they got to this solution ,,, that's why I'm asking for an explanation from U.

Comment: @sallyazzam If you look at the way I printed the array and what it turned out to be, you can map it directly to the code. Notice how the `halfSize` variable keeps splitting the array

Comment: it's just so hard for me to read other code including recursion not written by me ,I envy u guys , I don't know how u do it.

Comment: @sallyazzam Well, it's sad someone ask you to read so horrible code but... just practice... try to do it on paper, write it down step by step

Comment: @sallyazzam Notice how the size is turned into array index. First 7 then 3 and 10 then ....